# Modern pattern to write custom ostream operator

Tags: c++11, iostream, rvalue-reference

Typically, in C++, we used to define a custom ostream `operator<<` this way:

```
class A {
    int impl_;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, A const& self){
       return os << "A:" << self.impl_;
    }
};
```

However now, post C++11, there are r-value references, and as a matter of fact, built-in types can be streamed to r-value `std::ostream` references.
Now this is allowed:

```
int i = 5;
std::ofstream("file") << i;
```

(I don't know if this is the reason the special overloads were defined.)

Does it mean that for consistency one should define both operators for custom classes? Like this,

```
class A {
    int impl_;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, A const& self) {
       return os << "A:" << self.impl_;
    }
    friend std::ostream&& operator<<(std::ostream&& os, A const& self) {
       os << "A:" << self.impl_; 
       return std::move(os);
    }
};
```

or more streamlined,

```
class A {
    int impl_;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, A const& self) {
       return os << "A:" << self.impl_;
    }
    friend std::ostream&& operator<<(std::ostream&& os, A const& self) {
       return std::move(os << self); // calls the other overload
    }
};
```

What is the recommended way to overload `operator<<` nowadays in C++11?

Comment: I don't think the extra overload brings any benefits.

Comment: Off topic, but calling `std::move` from a return doesn't do anything at all, it just makes it difficult to do [unnamed] return value optimization and copy elision. Just return the value itself.

Comment: @cpplearner that can be argued about.  However that overload was defined for built-in types, there must be a logic for that. I don't think it is a bad idea to allow using the just created stream and be done with it.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8828973/why-does-the-rvalue-overload-of-operator-for-basic-ostream-return-an-lvalu

Comment: @MárioFeroldi That may be good advice for a function that returns a class type by value, but the `std::move` is required for a function as here that returns an rvalue reference.

Comment: @aschepler Functions should indeed not return rvalue references, just by value — C++ can avoid any copies in that case.

Comment: @Blaisorblade Usually, but there are some cases where returning rvalue via `std::move` is better. The template `std::operator` which takes any rvalue ostream (and makes the extra overload in this question unnecessary) returns by rvalue reference. If it returned by `std::ostream` value, the language would be forced to move-construct the return value, which does not take the `rdbuf()` with it, so a second insertion in a chain would fail.

Comment: @aschepler yes, I agree but even before that, more fundamentally, when people say not to return by such and such in C++ they have to take into account the possibility of returning function arguments or objects that use the resources provided by function arguments. This is one of the cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the conceptual discussion, from a technical viewpoint:

After some experimentation I realized that I don't need to overload for the r-value ostream, the library does it for me already.

One only has to have the l-value version and the library has some r-value version that is forwarded to the implemented overload, which presumably works for any std namespace argument of operator << through ADL or something.

So, in C++11, this is allowed `std::ofstream{"file"} << a`, even if no r-value overload (for the stream) is custom defined.

Which seems to make `operator<<` quite special in STL.

Corrections are welcome.