# Why does rvalue ostream operator<< not use perfect forwarding?

Tags: c++, std, rvalue, perfect-forwarding, stream-operators

Overloads for streaming objects into `std::ostream` and friends tend to only be written for lvalue ostreams.

Because it can be convenient to write code like `std::ofstream("myFile.txt") << "foo";`, the standard library is specified (in [`[ostream.rvalue]`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/ostream.rvalue)) to also provide the following `operator<<` overload that "translates" streaming into rvalue streams to streaming into lvalue streams:

```
template<class Ostream, class T> // (eliding SFINAE for readability)
Ostream&& operator<<(Ostream&& os, const T& val)
{
  os << val;
  return std::move(os);
}
```

<sup>See e.g. https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/1a418ba4e9c373aee7e9d6ef98efa4c2e2f6b9f4/stl/inc/ostream#L996 for a proper implementation. There is also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8828973/why-does-the-rvalue-overload-of-operator-for-basic-ostream-return-an-lvalu/8829047#8829047) discussion and the related [LWG issue](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#1203) about preserving most-derived type and/or rvalueness, which have been resolved in C++20 and are not the subject of my question.</sup>

Note that the second argument is taken as const ref. I would like to understand why it was specified that way. As it stands, I could readily write an `operator<<` overload for a move-only type, which will work fine with lvalue streams but fail with rvalue streams:

```
struct MoveOnly
{
    MoveOnly() = default;
    MoveOnly(const MoveOnly&) = delete;
    MoveOnly(MoveOnly&&) = default;
};

template <class C, class T>
std::basic_ostream<C, T>& operator<<(std::basic_ostream<C, T>&, MoveOnly x);

int main()
{
    // This works fine:
    std::stringstream s1{};
    s1 << MoveOnly{};
    // This does not compile (no suitable overload found):
    std::stringstream() << MoveOnly{};
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/1fexfs6Ex

**Why does the standard not employ perfect forwarding here?** Would there be a problem with something like:

```
template<class Ostream, class T> // (eliding SFINAE for readability)
Ostream&& operator<<(Ostream&& os, T&& val)
{
  os << std::forward<T>(val);
  return std::move(os);
}
```

I am writing similar code for my own stream-like class, and am wondering whether there is some disadvantage/problem I'm missing.

(The question of why this always returns the ostream instead of forwarding the inner `operator<<` result is also on my mind, but the answer to that seems quite clear.)

Comment: perfect forwarding gives you no advantage here and a `const` parameter guarantees to the caller that the passed in object will not be modified

Comment: I contest that the linked dupe answers my question. It is certainly not the same question, and no part of the answers covers the const-ness/value category of the second argument. Please take a closer look again (or elaborate how the dupe answers anything about my question).

Comment: @NathanOliver Sorry, can you elaborate how "my custom operator works with rvalue *and* lvalue ostreams" is "no advantage"? And why is this rvalue wrapper in the business of caring about whether the rhs object is modified - if the inner `operator<<` wants to modify it, let it do so?

Comment: I was talking about the value to be outputted, not the stream object.  There shouldn't be a need for that.  convention is that objects that are streamable provide an overload of `operator <<(stream&, const obj_type&)`.  If you forward to that nothing is going to change, so there is no need to have a forwarding reference.

Comment: "*convention is that objects that are streamable provide an overload of* `operator <<(stream&, const obj_type&)`" If you can source that, that sounds like the answer I am looking for!

Comment: @MaxLanghof It's a convention because that's how the standard library does it for every class type it provides that overload for.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Nice, I would happily accept that answer. (The supposed dupe notably does not contain any remotely related information. I don't know whether it's appropriate to gold-badge-reopen my own question though.)

Comment: @MaxLanghof Best I can find right now is the *Bitshift Operators (used for Stream I/O)* from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading).  I've also reopened the Q as I also disagree with it.