# Perfect return for functions modifying their argument

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, return-type

There is extensive discussion of perfect forwarding in templated functions, to allow efficient passing of either lvalues or rvalues arguments as parameters to other functions.

However, I am not able to find discussion of *perfect return* or equivalently *perfect pass-through*.
(The related question [Perfect pass-through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8826948/perfect-pass-through) does not fully address this.)

Consider the case of a function that modifies a range and should return the modified range.
We would need two separate functions to efficiently address the cases of lvalue and rvalue arguments:

```
// Given a reference to an lvalue range, return a reference to the same modified range.
// (There is no allocation or move.)
template<typename T> T& sortr(T& r) {
    std::sort(std::begin(r),std::end(r));
    return r;
}

// Given an rvalue range, return the same range via (hopefully) a move construction.
template<typename T> T sortr(T&& r) {
    std::sort(std::begin(r),std::end(r));
    return std::move(r);
}
```

Of course, including both definitions leads to ambiguity errors because the second one also matches lvalue references.

A motivating example (and test use) is the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<int>& v) {
    os << "["; for (int i : v) { os << " " << i; } os << " ]\n"; return os;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> c1{3,4,2,1};
    std::cerr << sortr(c1) << sortr(std::vector<int>({7,6,5,8}));
}
```

Can we define both versions of `sortr` using a single `template<typename T>` definition?

The challenge is that declaring the return type as `T&&` will only result (after template matching)
in a `T&&` or `T&` return type, not `T`.

Is it possible to define the appropriate template function using meta-programming on the return type?
Something like the following:

```
template<typename T> auto sortr(T&& r) ->
    typename std::conditional<std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value, T&, T>::type
{
    std::sort(std::begin(r),std::end(r));
    return std::forward<T>(r);
}
```

This seems to work, but I am unsure if it is safe and wise.  Any guidance would be welcome.

Comment: If `r` is bound to an rvalue of type `U`, `T` will be `U`. If `r` is bound to an lvalue of type `U`, `T` will be `U&`. As such, just use `T` as the return type, together with `std::forward`.

Comment: Does this talk help? http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/An-Effective-Cpp11-14-Sampler

Comment: "Of course, including both definitions leads to ambiguity errors because the second one also matches lvalue references"... if your compiler sucks.  There is a clause in the standard that says that if you have a `T&&` and a `T&` and both match, then `T&` wins.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use universal reference. In that case, you can return just `T`, but you need to change your template function to this :

```
template<typename T> T sortr(T && r) {
    std::sort(std::begin(r),std::end(r));
    return std::forward<T>(r);
}
```

---

Full example :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

template<typename T> T sortr(T && r) {
    std::sort(std::begin(r),std::end(r));
    return std::forward<T>(r);
}

std::vector<int> foo()
{
  return std::vector<int>(5,2);
}

void test( std::vector<int> & )
{
  std::cout<<"lvalue" << std::endl;
}
void test( std::vector<int> && )
{
  std::cout<<"rvalue" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> v(1,6);

  test( sortr( foo() ) );
  test( sortr( v ) );
}
```

---

If you do not know what universal reference is, take a look into [this talk by Scott Meyers](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Scott-Meyers-Universal-References-in-Cpp11).

Comment: Your `std::begin` and `std::end` is best done via a `using std::begin; using std::end;` then invoking `begin` and `end` naked.  This enables ADL on the type `T`, allowing custom classes with non-member `begin` `end` to work, just like `for( auto x:Y )` loops.

Comment: As a comment, `template<typename T> T&& sortr(T && r) {
    std::sort(std::begin(r),std::end(r));
    return std::forward<T>(r);
}` is tempting, but it has a subtle issue: if you assign the result of `sortr` to a reference, you don't get proper lifetime extension.  This causes problems when you `for( auto x: sortr( foo() ) )`, as (by the standard) it stores the iterated object in a reference.

Comment: @Yakk Regarding begin/end, I just copy pasted the code. I would probably call member methods.